# No arranca localhost en el puerto 3000 con Mongo DB

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, localhost

No tenia problema hasta que se me olvido ponerle un `async` al `await`.

Los errores que tengo son los siguientes:

```
PS C:\Users\Diego\Desktop\nodej-app> npm run dev

> nodej-app@1.0.0 dev C:\Users\Diego\Desktop\nodej-app
> nodemon src/index.js

[nodemon] 2.0.1
[nodemon] to restart at any time enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching dir(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node src/index.js`
(node:10692) DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed un a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoCLient constructor.
events.js:187
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
    ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3000
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1306:14)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1354:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1442:7)
    at Function.listen (C:\Users\Desktop\nodej-app\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:618:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Diego\Desktop\nodej-app\src\index.js:42:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1121:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1160:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:976:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:884:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:67:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1333:8)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
  code: 'EADDRINUSE',
  errno: -4091,
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '::',
  port: 3000
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: ya lo solucione gracias

Comment: Lo bueno es que si ya lo solucionaste puedes publicar la respuesta a tu pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

Eso quiere decir que ya tienes el puerto 3000 ocupado. Puedes tratar matando todos los proceso de Nodejs o verficiar que aplicación tiene el puerto 3000 ocupado.

Esto suele suceder cuando no manejas algún error en Nodejs y este deja el proceso corriendo.

En Windows puedes usar esto:

```
taskkill /im node.exe
```

Esto también te puede servir:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790910/stop-all-instances-of-node-js-server